# Android POST request with JSON

Tags: java, android, json, httpurlconnection

After researches i still cant send a JSON POST request to a server.

I already tried some older answers:

[Java - sending HTTP parameters via POST method easily](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205980/java-sending-http-parameters-via-post-method-easily)

[[Android]-POST Json with HttpUrlConnection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40238360/android-post-json-with-httpurlconnection)

[Post request for registering user data on server by HttpUrlConnection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38013669/post-request-for-registering-user-data-on-server-by-httpurlconnection)

[Sending json object via http post method in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36833798/sending-json-object-via-http-post-method-in-android)

[How to send a JSON object over Request with Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3027066/how-to-send-a-json-object-over-request-with-android?rq=1)

My current code is:

```
FloatingActionButton btn_sendMsg = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_sendMsg);
    btn_sendMsg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            /*Snackbar.make(view, "Sendevorgang...", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();*/

            createMsg();
        }
    });

private void createMsg() {
    Message message = new Message(txtbox_msg.getText().toString(), "testUser");

        AsyncT asyncT = new AsyncT();
        asyncT.execute(message);

}
```

AsyncT.java :

```
@Override
protected Message doInBackground(Message... params) {

    try {
        URL url = new URL("http://[ip]:[port]"); //in the real code, there is an ip and a port
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept","application/json");
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.connect();

        JSONObject jsonParam = new JSONObject();
        jsonParam.put("uname", params[0].getUser());
        jsonParam.put("message", params[0].getMessage());
        jsonParam.put("latitude", "0");
        jsonParam.put("longitude", "0");
        jsonParam.put("id", "1");


        DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
        os.writeBytes(URLEncoder.encode(jsonParam.toString(), "UTF-8"));

        os.flush();
        os.close();

        Log.i("STATUS", String.valueOf(conn.getResponseCode()));
        Log.i("MSG" , conn.getResponseMessage());

        conn.disconnect();
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }


    return null;
}
```

I'm getting the error code networkonmainthreadexception 500

How can i solve this?

Comment: Could you add your stacktrace?

Comment: networkonmainthreadexception 500 is  may b causing because of server-side issues. You might check on to that.

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel once again, there is no point of using asynctask (it's crap), httpsurlconnection (as there are better alternatives like okhttp/volley), manual json parsing (what for if it can be done automatically with gson/jackson). Just use retrofit: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Retrofit/article.html

Comment: `getting the error code networkonmainthreadexception 500`. Nonsense. 500 means something different.

Comment: You are posting to what kind of server? Please show the script.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

**Solved:**

changed

```
os.writeBytes(URLEncoder.encode(jsonParam.toString(), "UTF-8"));
```

to

```
os.writeBytes(jsonParam.toString());
```

And put the code in a thread (thanks to @Ravi Sanker)

Working code:

```
public void sendPost() {
    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                URL url = new URL(urlAdress);
                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Accept","application/json");
                conn.setDoOutput(true);
                conn.setDoInput(true);

                JSONObject jsonParam = new JSONObject();
                jsonParam.put("timestamp", 1488873360);
                jsonParam.put("uname", message.getUser());
                jsonParam.put("message", message.getMessage());
                jsonParam.put("latitude", 0D);
                jsonParam.put("longitude", 0D);

                Log.i("JSON", jsonParam.toString());
                DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
                //os.writeBytes(URLEncoder.encode(jsonParam.toString(), "UTF-8"));
                os.writeBytes(jsonParam.toString());

                os.flush();
                os.close();

                Log.i("STATUS", String.valueOf(conn.getResponseCode()));
                Log.i("MSG" , conn.getResponseMessage());

                conn.disconnect();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    thread.start();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Can you try with writing this in the createMsg() method:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

@Override
public void run() {
    try  {
        // The code written in doInBackground()
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}});

thread.start();
```

The networkonmainthread exception comes when you run the network operations on the same thread. But, since you're using an async task, it should work fine. But, just to confirm.

Comment: i'll try tomorrow and write back.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/raw/FyRbkrpZ fixes the networkonmainthread exception